# trying to update object value with each click but not working - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, addeventlistener

I am trying to update the value of num inside my object each time i click a button. However I can not get it to work. I am printing the object to the console each time I click so i can see if the value updates but it doesn't. Here is my code... any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
const addToCart = document.getElementById('addToCart')
            addToCart.addEventListener('click', function(option) {
                option.preventDefault();   
                
                let num = 0
              
                let cartObject = {
                    name: jsonResponse.name,
                    price: jsonResponse.price,
                    option: select.value,
                    optionQuantity: num
                }
                num++
                
                console.log(cartObject)    
            });
```

Comment: just move the line `let num = 0` to outside of function.. before `addToCart.addEventListener`

Comment: The entire function runs each time that button is clicked. This includes the line where you declare `num`. It is declared, initialized to `0`, then used in the object creation. It's then increased by one (however, `cartObject.optionQuantity` will still be zero). After the console.log line, both `num` and `cartObject` cease to exist. On the next click, all this happens again, exactly like the first time, without any consequences for anything living outside that function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move your `let num = 0` to outside of your function block. Because when you invoke this function each time it's executes `let num = 0`. That why `num` never changes.